# Does King Bob-omb’s health reset if you throw him off the mountain?

Tags: super-mario-64

When Mario fights King Bob-omb in Bob-omb Battlefield, if the king throws Mario off the mountain, the fight will restart and the King will be restored to full health.

In contrast, if Mario tries to throw King Bob-omb off the mountain, he will jump back up and chastise Mario for fighting unfairly before resuming the battle.

Hypocrisy aside, this made me wonder:

**Does King Bob-omb get restored to full health if you throw him off the mountain?**

Comment: That's really early in the game, have you tried testing this theory yourself? What happened that caused the uncertainty?

Comment: @Kozaky I don’t currently have access to a copy of Mario 64, which is why I can’t test this for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A YouTube video has the answer:

His health does not reset.  Three legal throws and he loses.  Illegal throws do not count, but neither does it reset.